# Why can't I use the Lamborghini #63 Squadra Corse Huracán?

Tags: forza-horizon-3

I completed the Forzathon event, jumping the airfield danger sign, to unlock the Horizon Edition Lamborghini Huracán, which I can use just fine.

However I've also noticed a racing version in my garage. Which is marked with a DLC marker.

[image: Squadra Corse]

When I try and select this car, the game starts looking for purchase options, and then I get this message.

[image: Marktplace error]

Is this a bug with the game? A bug with my game save? A glitch or what? I've raced against other Drivatars using this car, so I know it's playable.

I'm playing on Windows, with the [Expansion Pass](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/forza-horizon-3-expansion-pass/9nblggh4t5ft) and [Car Pass](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/forza-horizon-3-car-pass/9nblggh4t3fd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This car was given away to everyone as a promotional car to celebrate the Forza Liveried Huracan in real life that ran at a real life race.

However, the actual car still needs to be purchased from the Car Pack that includes it, which is the Motorsports All Stars Car Pack. Once you've purchased the pack/car, you should be able to drive the #63 currently in your garage.

For some reason, the gift Huracan is not correctly linked to the store.

Here it is in the store
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/forza-horizon-3-motorsport-all-stars-pack/9nblggh4rlgl?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: So it's not included as part of the Car Pass I guess. That's what caught me out. Thanks I've bought the pack and got access to the car, but it has a different design when loaded. Strange!

Comment: @DavidYell Yes, it's a quirk with all the gift cars. The #63 you got as a gift has the livery that was used on the real life Forza Car.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct then it also comes with the ultimate version with all the other cars that come with the game such as the racing 458 italia.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer would be greatly improved if you were to add a source supporting it.